# Catching element with childNodes() - Simple HTML DOM?

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I use Simple HTML DOM to catch dynamic content from other sites. Because the content is dynamic, it's always at a different position. I'm trying with **childNodes()**. It's working, but only if I know the position of the element.

The content varies between 5 to 15 elements. I'm very weak with PHP, so I'm thinking about looping that change the number of the elements and then if successful getting the **id**, bringing it out of the loop and insetting the element into the **DB**. I don't know if that is the right way, but I can't bring the **id** out of the loop. **Is there some way to do it?**

***Here's my code:***

```
   foreach($html->find('.article') as $e) // Get Other Part of the Description
    {               
        for($i = 7; $i < 20; $i++)
        {

              $details_download=$e->childNodes($i); 

        }

   }
```

Comment: Without seeing the content you're trying to scrape, I can only suggest looking into using xpath to select the elements you require.

Comment: The content is very complex, they use the wysiwyg editor to edit the content and each time a different location can not accurately say where, and on top there are no attributes to be caught.

Comment: Either give us the HTML you are scrapping, or a URL to the HTML. Then give us an example or explanation of what you are trying to extract.